# Dump a database using Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is there any way to dump a database using Doctrine from Symfony?

I looked at `doctrine:schema:create` but it seems to do another job: it makes schema from entities.

I need something to:

- dump database schema
- load schema
- remove all the data from database

How can I do it with Doctrine? May be it has some classes for these tasks and I can write own commands?

P.S. I've seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071669/dump-database-data-using-doctrine-2), but I heard that it has migrations, so these functions should exist.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ElnurAbdurrakhimov TDD with testing database and fixtures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to dump for migrating, doctrine is not built for that and there is no tool.
If you just need the schema and don't care about the data within your database you can just recreate everything with the doctrine create tool and hang a --dump-sql.

```
php doctrine orm:schema-tool:create --dump-sql
```

Read the warning on the docu page: [Doctrine tools docu page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html)

If you want to do it from php rather from the console, you can use it like this (also from the docu):

```
<?php
$tool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($em);
$classes = array(
  $em->getClassMetadata('Entities\User'),
  $em->getClassMetadata('Entities\Profile')
);
$tool->createSchema($classes);
```

For migrating you should dump (can do it from code or console) and keep track of what is what with git or similar. Than you can import from file with doctrine.

Comment: I have entities only for part of the database. So I can't generate full schema using this method, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mysql you can mysqldump utility. But regarding loading database fixtures you should probably use [DoctrineFixturesBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html).

Comment: It's not a solution: some of the queries use DBAL.