# Automatic database population in Symfony

Tags: database, symfony

is it possible in Symfony to have data prepopulated into some of the tables I have set up. Perhaps I can create some annotations on the models I want to have data populated into, or an SQL script that gets run once?

Does anyone have any ideas about such a thing?

Thank you

Comment: [Unfortunately not on Symfony's side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071669/dump-database-data-using-doctrine-2)

You could write yourself an install script that executes a SQL import into a database though

Answer (score 0):

That is called fixtures. If you are using Doctrine check out the DoctrineFixturesBundle

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html