# Symfony - database dump with all content

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony

I am developing a backup system. I want to backup my database will all it rows.

I have found something, but it is not what exactly i need

```
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$schemaTool = new SchemaTool($em);
$metadatas = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();

$sqls = $schemaTool->getCreateSchemaSql($metadatas);
```

It just creates the schema, but not the content. 
I'm using Postgresql.

How should i get my database dump with contents in php/symfony ?

thank you!

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071669/dump-database-data-using-doctrine-2).  TBH, if youre looking to backup your database on a server, you should be using a cron job + script. Not relying on the framework.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to do it through Symfony? Can't you use shell scripts and crons?

Comment: use `mysqldump` from mysql symfony is not needed.

Comment: Not important it will be script or symfony. Im looking for any solution. Robert, cant you see, i wrote i'm using Postgresql.

Comment: so use `pg_dump dbname > outfile` which is still better than using framework

Comment: Okay, i will try it, Thank you